# iOS Status bar turned black by Photo Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app uses white status bar text throughout.  I've accomplished this through numerous settings below:

1/ In Info.plist I set: View controller-based status bar appearance to "NO"

2/ In - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` I set `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]`;

3/ I implemented the following in the VC I am asking about here:

```
 - (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

4/ In Storyboard I set the Navigation Bar Style to "Black"

So, a ton of different ways to make sure a simple status bar stays with white text.  This is working throughout except for when the users goes to the picture library or the user goes to take a picture.  This of course launches Apple's framework which uses a black status bar.  That is fine for those controllers as again they are dictated by Apple.  However, when the user then cancels or chooses an image and are returned to my controllers, the status bar stays black.  I've tried the following when it returns: `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` but that also does not work.

How can I get the status bar to return to white text after it returns from the Apple controlled photo picker views?  I am working with iOS 8 although a check shows that this same problem occurs in 7.1.  This happens with both the simulator and real devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer which was to repeat what I did in my step 2 above within the VC that the image picker returns to.  So in viewWillAppear I execute: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` again.  Seems like a lot of different ways just to get a status bar to stay white, but now it does under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will resolve your problem as it resolves mine
Write the code for `UIImagePicker` and its delegate, add `willShowViewController` method which is delegate of `UINavigationController`.
There set the status bar style to LightContent.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]] &&
         (((UIImagePickerController *)navigationController).sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)) || (((UIImagePickerController *)navigationController).sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary))
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I actually did find a solution which is a bit more straightforward.  I will post it.